# How to assign values into the proxied data in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Here's a simple code

```js
        testobject = {};
        testobject.number = 444;
        
        someapp = {
           data(){
              return testobject;
           },
           methods: {
              test(){
                 this.number++;
              }
           }
        }
        
        app = Vue.createApp(someapp);
        app.mount("#sss");
```

A button that has a `v-on:click="test"` will call the test() method, and it will increase the `number` property. `testobject.number` will also go up.

What I'm wondering is what I have to do to change number, from say, the javascript console. `testobject.number++` doesn't work, `someapp.number` or `app.number` does not exist.

So what is the way to do that in Vue 3? In Vue 2 I was able to change testobject's members and watch changes happen - seems like I have to do something extra here.

Additionally, how can I call the `test` method, from the javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `app` is the [*application instance*, not the *component instance*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html).

The result of [`app.mount()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#mount) is the root component instance, which would give you access to the component's data and methods:

```js
app = Vue.createApp(someapp).mount("#sss");

app.number++
app.test()
```